# make list of links from unique values in a column in a database android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite database in my android application. There are 3 fields in a table:

**id**  |  **thing**  |  **tags**

The information is stored as follows:

01 |  car  |  wheels;engine;windscreen;chairs;

02  |  wheelbarrow  |  tools;wheels;push;

So everything in the tags field will be separated by a semi-colon.

As you can see, there are many different tags, but now I want to get ALL the different tags, but only once, and then make a linked list out of each tag (to pass through to another class that will pick up what tag they clicked on).

The desired output is:

- wheels
- engine
- windscreen
- chairs
- tools
- push

**NB: NOTE that the `wheels` were not printed twice, only once. So the values must not repeat**

Is it possible to do this? How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider redesigning the schema so that tags have a table of their own and there's a many-to-many relationship between the things and tags tables.

For example

```
CREATE TABLE tags(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE thingtags(thingid INTEGER REFERENCES things(id), tagid INTEGER REFERENCES tags(id), PRIMARY KEY(thingid,tagid));
```

Then to get the tags that are used at least once

```
SELECT name FROM tags WHERE id IN (SELECT tagid FROM thingtags);
```

Comment: When I try to use two tables, it says the one table does not exist? even though I use the exact same code to create it right under my first one?